# Check for null value in Azure Policy

Tags: azure-policy

My requirement is to set TAGS to resource groups. I have to make sure anyone who creates Resource Groups should provide appropriate tags and values. I want to use Azure Policy to enforce checking that a TAG should not have NULL value. I am using the below Policy definition, but it seems not to be working properly. That is, it is allowing me to create resource groups with TAG having null values. Example: Environment = "" --> This tag should not be allowed and RG group creation should fail.

Policy Definition:

```
    "parameters": {
      "tagName": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Tag Name",
          "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
        }
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
          },
          {
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
            "exists": "true"
          },
          {
            "value": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
            "equals": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: you can find the correct policy definition here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61356867/azure-policy-check-for-an-empty-value

Answer (score 0):

This policy only enforces the tagName not the tagValue. To enforce both follow this built in: [Require a tag and its value on resource groups](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyDetailBlade/definitionId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyDefinitions%2F8ce3da23-7156-49e4-b145-24f95f9dcb46)

Comment: Thank you, but how do i check for the condition that the TAG value should not be a NULL value

Comment: "notequals":" "

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
  {
    "not": {
      "value": "[contains(string(field('tags')), '\"\"')]",
      "equals": true
    }
  }
```

Option 2:

```
  {
    "value": "[indexOf(string(field('tags')), '\"\"')]",
    "greaterOrEquals": 0
  }
```

**Description:**
Option 1:
Use `contains` to check wheather an object contains a key or a string contains a substring.
The `container` contains nested parameters.
`string` converts the specified value to a string. In this case, the specified value is the `field = tags`, which are objects, not an array. In this case, the specified value is the field = tags, which are `objects`, not an `array`.
Example of 2 tags, "tagnumber1" with the value "value1" and "tagnumber2" with an empty value:
`"{\"tagnumber1\":\"value1\",\"tagnumber2\":\"\"}"`
Note that the empty value is `\"\"` - this is our `itemToFind`.

Option 2:
Use the `indexOf` to return the first position of a value within a string.
The `stringToSearch` contains nested parameters.
The `stringToFind` is empty.
`string` converts the specified value to a string. In this case, the specified value is the `field = tags`, which are `objects`, not an `array`.
Example of 2 tags, "tagnumber1" with the value "value1" and "tagnumber2" with an empty value:
`"{\"tagnumber1\":\"value1\",\"tagnumber2\":\"\"}"`
Note that the empty value is `\"\"`.
Therefore, we must search for that `\"\"` as this represents the empty value in the object.
The index is zero-based. If the item is not found, -1 is returned. An integer represents the first index of the item, so by looking at `"greaterOrEquals": 0` it will only return that is the item is found - meaning a tag value is empty.

Links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#fields
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-expressions#escape-characters
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template#resource-format-1