# Azure Policy check for an empty value

Tags: azure, tags, policy, notnull, azure-policy

I need an Azure Policy for tagging. I want that a user needs to define a tag when a Resource Groups is created. The Policy should also check that the tagvaule is not empty.

i have tried the following:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Require a tag Billto and a value that is not empty",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "All",
    "description": "Enforces a required tag and its value on resource groups.",
    "metadata": {
      "category": "Tags",
    },
    "parameters": {
      "tagName": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Tag Name",
          "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'Billto'"
        }
      },
      "tagValue": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Tag Value",
          "description": "Value of the tag, such as 'Costcenter'"
        }
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
          },
          {
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
            "exists": "false"
          },
          {
            "value": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagValue'), ']')]",
            "equals": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
      }
    }
  }
```

can someone help me and give me the right code?
Thanks Thomas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This policy definition will deny resource groups which have an empty value for the given tag, or are missing the tag altogether:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "mode": "All",
    "parameters": {
      "tagName": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Tag Name",
          "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'Billto'"
        }
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
          },
          {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
                "exists": false
              },
              {
                "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
                "equals": ""
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Breaking it down:

1. `parameters('tagName')` resolves to the value of the parameter tagName. For the rest of this example, we'll use `Billto` as the tag name.
2. `"field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]"` resolves to `"field": "tags[Billto]"`
3. `"field": "tags[Billto]"` will get the *value* of the `Billto` tag.
4. If the resource doesn't have a `Billto` tag, The `Billto` tag won't have a value, so the `"exists" : false` will be true and the policy will deny. If the `Billto` tag's value is empty, then `"equals": ""` will be true, and the policy will deny.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another solution in case you want to check if one or multiple of your tags are empty. The accepted solution only works with a single tag/tagvalue.

Option 1:

```
  {
    "not": {
      "value": "[contains(string(field('tags')), '\"\"')]",
      "equals": true
    }
  }
```

Option 2:

```
  {
    "value": "[indexOf(string(field('tags')), '\"\"')]",
    "greaterOrEquals": 0
  }
```

**Description:**
Option 1:
Use `contains` to check wheather an object contains a key or a string contains a substring.
The `container` contains nested parameters.
`string` converts the specified value to a string. In this case, the specified value is the `field = tags`, which are objects, not an array. In this case, the specified value is the field = tags, which are `objects`, not an `array`.
Example of 2 tags, "tagnumber1" with the value "value1" and "tagnumber2" with an empty value:
`"{\"tagnumber1\":\"value1\",\"tagnumber2\":\"\"}"`
Note that the empty value is `\"\"` - this is our `itemToFind`.

Option 2:
Use the `indexOf` to return the first position of a value within a string.
The `stringToSearch` contains nested parameters.
The `stringToFind` is empty.
`string` converts the specified value to a string. In this case, the specified value is the `field = tags`, which are `objects`, not an `array`.
Example of 2 tags, "tagnumber1" with the value "value1" and "tagnumber2" with an empty value:
`"{\"tagnumber1\":\"value1\",\"tagnumber2\":\"\"}"`
Note that the empty value is `\"\"`.
Therefore, we must search for that `\"\"` as this represents the empty value in the object.
The index is zero-based. If the item is not found, -1 is returned. An integer represents the first index of the item, so by looking at `"greaterOrEquals": 0` it will only return that is the item is found - meaning a tag value is empty.

Links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#fields
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-expressions#escape-characters
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template#resource-format-1